# Ruby update value using detect

Tags: ruby

I have a complex data structure (multiple levels of arrays of hashes).  I want to find and update a specific value.  However, `detect` does not seem to pass the reference to the location in the data structure that I want to update.  I can code this using `each` or `each_with_object` but that would iterate over ALL the data when I want to stop @ the first match.  In my actual program, `"mymouse"` and `485` are variables representing those values.

What single line command can update this entry?
Why does `detect` not work like `each{}` in terms of being able to modify the data?  I would expect this to work since Ruby is pass-by-reference.

```
mynew = [{:mouse=>{:cat=>[485, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7], :dog=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, :name=>"mymouse"}, {:name=>"mymouse", :mouse=>{:cat=>[485, 11, 10], :dog=>[45, 54, 65]}}]

# Finds the value I want to update to 12
puts mynew.detect{|f| f[:name] == "mymouse"}[:mouse][:cat].detect{|x| x==485}

# results in an error
mynew.detect{|f| f[:name] == "mymouse"}[:mouse][:cat].detect{|x| x==485} = 12

# Does not update the value to 12
location = mynew.detect{|f| f[:name] == "mymouse"}[:mouse][:cat].detect{|x| x==485}
location = 12
puts mynew     # Value unchanged
```

Comment: When you write `location = 12` you are totally throwing out the previous value stored in the `location` variable; you are not modifying the object that `location` used to point to.  Ruby's references are more like Java/C#/Python references than C++ references.

Comment: Could I do something ugly like `location.to_s.sub!(/.*/,"12").to_i` ?  Or is there a corresponding command?  I tried `location.replace 12` and it didn't like that.

Comment: I tried the sub! idea and it doesn't work

Comment: If you do `location.to_s` then you are creating a new string that isn't referred to by your data structure, and modifying it doesn't do any good.  It will get garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
data = [
  {
    :name=>"mymouse",
    :mouse=>{
      :cat=>[485, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7],
      :dog=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    },
  },
  {
    :name=>"othermouse",
    :mouse=>{
      :cat=>[485, 11, 10],
      :dog=>[45, 54, 65]
    }
  }
]

entry = data.find { |f| f[:name] == "mymouse" }
array = entry[:mouse][:cat]
modified_array = array.map { |n| n == 485 ? 12 : n }
entry[:mouse][:cat] = modified_array

require 'pp'
pp data
```

This will work; I tested it.

Alternatively, once you have the array you could just use:

```
array[array.index(485)] = 12
```

This modifies the original array, so it could have a different effect than the main solution I posted, which does not modify the original array.

Comment: Thanks for the response; is there a way to make this 1 line?  If I can `puts` the value contained at that reference in 1 line, surely I can also update the value in 1 line (somehow)?

Comment: I think the closest you can reasonably get without repeating a lot of code is two lines:
`array = data.find { |f| f[:name] == "mymouse" }[:mouse][:cat]; array[array.index(485)] = 12`

Comment: David, any idea why `find` can't pass a modify-able reference?  I can run the `data.find { |f| f[:name] == "mymouse" }[:mouse][:cat].tap{}` (proving that the reference can get passed to later in the line) but of course `tap` would not modify the original value.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a modifiable reference in the way you were hoping.  `find` can return a reference to some object, and if it happens to be a modifiable object (like `Hash`, `String`, `Array`, `Set`, etc.) then you can call class-specific methods like `Array#[]=` or `String#gsub!` on that object to modify it.  The `=` operator is not a method and has no effect on the object previously referred to by the variable.  Integers are not modifiable.  It seems like you've done a lot of advanced C++ programming and this is your first scripting language, is that true?

Comment: Yes, I suspect that my SystemC experience is trying to spill over into Ruby.  I've toyed around with Perl previously but decided to transition entirely to Ruby for my scripting needs.  Thanks for your clear explanations, it was very helpful.